# Which dependencies are updated via "ng update" command?

Tags: angular

I'm updating an Angular app and there are some dependencies that are not on newest version.

From what I know some of them must be on the earlier version as this is the version internally used by Angular, e.g. TypeScript, Karma, core-js.

I would like to find out if there is a list of dependencies that is handled by `ng update`, so that I don't acidentally update them manually.

Edit: I'm looking for a list of dependencies (best with versions related to specific version of Angular) that are magaged by `ng update`. Right now I am confused if I should update tslint and @types/node or just leave it as it is now.

Comment: I think `ng update` is updating only installed global @angular/cli application. If You want to download not update any library in Your project use command `npm install`. If You want to update any library to newer wersion you need to do it manually one by one.

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge, `ng update` update all original packages, that is installed when you run `ng new`

Comment: What I'm trying to find is list of them (with right versions to use), so that I'm sure that they can stay as they are now. For example I'm not sure about @type/node and tslint.

Comment: I use the latest version for all packages except for "typescript"

`"typescript": ">=3.4.0 and <3.6.0"`